# How to generate fingerprint from public ssh key in php?

Tags: php, ssh-keys

I have an application that needs pub ssh key and fingerprint, how can I generate fingerprint from only *Public SSH Key*?

I just want my users paste their ssh key and I generate fingerprint in php function and show it to theme.

thanks

Comment: Look at this https://gist.github.com/Xeoncross/5326443

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but with this method I should use a file to handle it.It just run Linux command. I don't want to do  this. I want to get ssh key from user and then in a function generate fingerprint and after that save to the DB.

Comment: You don't need to use files. Read the post more attentively.

Comment: Hmm yes!!! Thank you dude. :)